# Proper formate for ipywidgets customJS callback regarding extra_y_ranges in Bokeh plot

Tags: python, bokeh, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I need help in the proper format for the customJS callback formate for an extra_y_ranges

This code works as expected:

```
    range_slider = RangeSlider(value=(Ymin.value,Ymax.value),start=0, end=4000, step=.1, title="Stuff")
    range_slider.js_link("value", tps.y_range, "start", attr_selector=0)
    range_slider.js_link("value", tps.y_range, "end", attr_selector=1)
```

attempting to get a second slider for a second Y range, this code does not work.

```
    range_slider1 = RangeSlider(value=(Y2ndLLimit.value,Y2ndULimit.value),start=0, end=4000, step=.1,                         title="Stuff")
    range_slider1.js_link("value", tps.extra_y_ranges('Speed'), "start", attr_selector=0)
    range_slider1.js_link("value", tps.extra_y_ranges('Speed'), "end", attr_selector=1)
```

I have the extra range define properly and the code works fine if the above is commented out.
The problem lise in "tps.extra_y_ranges('Speed')".

I've tried various formats to `tps.extra_y_ranges('Speed')`
including:

```
    tps.extra_y_ranges(['Speed'])
    tps.extra_y_ranges{'Speed'}
    tps.extra_y_ranges{Speed}
    tps.extra_y_ranges.attr('Speed')
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct format to be:

```
 range_slider1.js_link("value", tps.extra_y_ranges['Speed'], "start", attr_selector=0)
```